# Blender Python API lines execution seems "not in order"

Tags: python, scripting, blender, add-on

I am writing a script for batch rendering (multiple renderings from different cameras), but it seems that Blender executes some lines before or at the same time as the next lines.

Here is the code:

```
import bpy

# Funzioni

def open_rendering_workspace(context):
try:
if bpy.context.window.workspace != bpy.data.workspaces\['Rendering'\]:
bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces\['Rendering'\]
except:
bpy.ops.workspace.append_activate(idname="Rendering", filepath=bpy.utils.user_resource('CONFIG', path='startup.blend'))
return {"FINISHED"}

def render_batch(self, overwrite=True):

    # Cerca la collection
    try:
        cameras = bpy.data.collections["Cameras"]
    except:
        self.report({'ERROR'}, 'Deve esistere una collection chiamata "Cameras"')
        return {"CANCELLED"}
    
    # Imposta render slot (overwrite)
    if overwrite:
        bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = 0
    else:
        try:
            bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = active_slot
        except:
            bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = 0
    
    # Algoritmo principale
    for object in cameras.objects:
        
        # Verifica camera
        if object.type == "CAMERA":
            
            # Imposta la camera
            camera = object
            bpy.context.scene.camera = camera
             
            # Render
            bpy.ops.render.view_show("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
            bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True)
             
            # Aggiunta render slot
            if bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index + 1 == len(bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots):
                bpy.ops.image.add_render_slot()
             
            # Imposta render slot
            bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index += 1
            active_slot = bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index
    
    # Resetta lo slot attivo per la visualizzazione
    bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = 0
    return {"FINISHED"}

# Operatori

class RENDER_OT_render_batch(bpy.types.Operator):
"""Execute render batch"""
bl_idname = "render.render_batch"
bl_label = "Render Batch"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        # Apre il workspace di rendering
        open_rendering_workspace(context)
        
        bpy.ops.image.read_viewlayers()
        
        # Esegue l'algoritmo
        render_batch(self)
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Menu

def menu_draw(self, context):
self.layout.operator(RENDER_OT_render_batch.bl_idname, icon="RENDERLAYERS")

# Register e unregister

def register():
bpy.utils.register_class(RENDER_OT_render_batch)
bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_render.prepend(menu_draw)

def unregister():
bpy.utils.unregister_class(RENDER_OT_render_batch)
bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_render.remove(menu_draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
register()
```

In particular in "RENDER_OT_render_batch", the rendering (on line 56, in the "render_batch" function) seems to be executed before the "Rendering" workspace is opened via the function on line 18 (called on line 83) that sets the workspace as active (if it does not exist it creates one first).
I would like to know if there is a way to not have one line execute until the execution of another one finishes.

I also don't understand how to set the "Render Result" in the image editor via code when I create a new render workspace, but that is a minor problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I tried putting the workspace activation in the "open_rendering_workspace" function, instead of a few lines before the one that does the rendering, I searched online, but couldn't find much.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python source code was not pasted in correctly, and is missing some whitespace which is necessary to get the code to run. I was able to reproduce your error using this code:

```
import bpy

# Funzioni

def open_rendering_workspace(context):
    try:
        if bpy.context.window.workspace != bpy.data.workspaces['Rendering']:
            bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['Rendering']
    except:
        bpy.ops.workspace.append_activate(idname="Rendering", filepath=bpy.utils.user_resource('CONFIG', path='startup.blend'))
    return {"FINISHED"}

def render_batch(self, overwrite=True):

    # Cerca la collection
    try:
        cameras = bpy.data.collections["Cameras"]
    except:
        self.report({'ERROR'}, 'Deve esistere una collection chiamata "Cameras"')
        return {"CANCELLED"}
    
    # Imposta render slot (overwrite)
    if overwrite:
        bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = 0
    else:
        try:
            bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = active_slot
        except:
            bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = 0
    
    # Algoritmo principale
    for object in cameras.objects:
        
        # Verifica camera
        if object.type == "CAMERA":
            
            # Imposta la camera
            camera = object
            bpy.context.scene.camera = camera
             
            # Render
            bpy.ops.render.view_show("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
            bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True)
             
            # Aggiunta render slot
            if bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index + 1 == len(bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots):
                bpy.ops.image.add_render_slot()
             
            # Imposta render slot
            bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index += 1
            active_slot = bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index
    
    # Resetta lo slot attivo per la visualizzazione
    bpy.data.images['Render Result'].render_slots.active_index = 0
    return {"FINISHED"}

# Operatori

class RENDER_OT_render_batch(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Execute render batch"""
    bl_idname = "render.render_batch"
    bl_label = "Render Batch"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        # Apre il workspace di rendering
        open_rendering_workspace(context)
        
        bpy.ops.image.read_viewlayers()
        
        # Esegue l'algoritmo
        render_batch(self)
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Menu

def menu_draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(RENDER_OT_render_batch.bl_idname, icon="RENDERLAYERS")

# Register e unregister

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RENDER_OT_render_batch)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_render.prepend(menu_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RENDER_OT_render_batch)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_render.remove(menu_draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

In order to not get the error

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../RenderBatchScript.blend/RenderBatch", line 69, in execute
  File "/app/blender/3.6/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.image.read_viewlayers.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

I manually created a "Render" context by using the "Add Workspace" button on the menu ribbon. It looks like a "+"
[the "add context" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXPaO.png)
Press this button, and then select General > Rendering

Once this is done, the script no longer gives the "context is incorrect" error, and instead switches to the "Render" workspace.